# React BrowserRouter : Uncought Error - Invalid Hook Call

Tags: reactjs

I am following a React Tutorial, and I created the bare bones of my app using "npm react-create-app ", Installed the "react-route-dom" and started the server. This is my first time trying to create a react app so I installed everything today.

I looked at other people who posted about a similar problem and I tried to apply their fixes but still not working. I tried the following :

1. Removing the Modules folder and the Package.json and re-installing with NPM.
2. Checking if I have a double react file and checking my if React & React DOM are different versions.
3. Tutorial code used a Class Component & I switched it to a function.

My Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './Components/App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My Component App.js

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
} from 'react-router-dom'


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <h3>Hello World</h3>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}

export default App;
```

My Dependencies

```
{
  "name": "newworld",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
```

I have no idea where the error might be, any help would be wonderful,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by Uninstalling Node.js and removing all modules from my computer and doing a fresh re-install of everything and now it works.